# erlang: failed to spawn(node, fun): badfun error

Tags: erlang

The remote node is located in the different machine.

I test from the local node:

```
$ erl -name foobar
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V6.2  (abort with ^G)
(foobar@debian.localdomain)1> Aliyun='aliyun@localhost2.localdomain'.
'aliyun@localhost2.localdomain'
(foobar@debian.localdomain)2> spawn(Aliyun, fun() -> io:format("hello~n") end).
<6108.86.0>
(foobar@debian.localdomain)3> 
=ERROR REPORT==== 4-Jul-2015::21:03:27 ===
Error in process <0.86.0> on node 'aliyun@localhost2.localdomain' with exit value: {{badfun,#Fun<erl_eval.20.90072148>},[{erlang,apply,2,[]}]}


(foobar@debian.localdomain)3> spawn(Aliyun, io, format, ["hello~n"]).          
hello
<6108.87.0>
(foobar@debian.localdomain)4> net_adm:ping(Aliyun).
pong
```

You could see that `spawn(node,module,function,args)` works, but the `spawn(node,fun)` does not.

The Erlang version on the remote node is R15, while the version on the local node is R17. Is it the reason? Because the code format is different? I'm not clear how Erlang marshal the fun type when passing it to the remote node. In bytecode?

Help please!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the error message you received shows, the anonymous function is essentially treated in this context as if it were defined in the `erl_eval` module. If you have the same version of `erl_eval` on both the sending node and receiving node, everything works fine, since in that case both copies of `erl_eval` have the same version and checksums, so the receiving node is correctly able to evaluate an anonymous function passed from the sending node. But if the two nodes have different `erl_eval` modules, evaluating the anonymous function will fail.

An interesting thing to try is to define the anonymous function on the R15 node, convert it to a binary via `term_to_binary/1`, send or copy the resulting binary over to the 17.x node, convert it back to a term via `binary_to_term/1`, and then pass the resulting term as the anonymous function to your `spawn` call. First, on the R15 node:

```
(r15@myhost)1> F = fun() -> io:format("hello~n") end.
(r15@myhost)2> Bin = term_to_binary(F).
<<131,112,0,0,2,179,0,158,45,156,12,16,101,74,154,214,21,
  222,196,219,108,205,131,0,0,0,20,0,0,...>>
(r15@myhost)3> file:write_file("/tmp/fun", Bin).
ok
```

Now read the binary into the 17.x node, and make the `spawn` call with it back over to the R15 node:

```
(r17@myhost)1> {ok, Bin} = file:read_file("/tmp/fun").
{ok,<<131,112,0,0,2,179,0,158,45,156,12,16,101,74,154,
      214,21,222,196,219,108,205,131,0,0,0,20,...>>}
(r17@myhost)2> F = binary_to_term(Bin).
#Fun<erl_eval.20.82930912>
(r17@myhost)3> spawn(r15@myhost, F).
hello
<7101.90.0>
```

As you can see — and you should try it for yourself too — the `spawn` call works as expected because the anonymous function was created on the R15 node and it's also being evaluated there. The 17.x node merely passes it through.

Comment: Why it's restricted to be the same version of erl_eval? As long as the fun is compatible with the target version, i.e. the referred functions and semantics are compatible, then it should run on the target Erlang, which is more flexible, because you could exchange arbitrary compatible codes between the nodes, besides the prepared modules.

Comment: How do you propose verifying compatibility of a module's functions and semantics such that arbitrary anonymous funs associated with that module can be executed correctly across different nodes? Solving that problem generally is impractical. The Erlang runtime therefore checks the MD5 checksum of the module to verify compatibility.